# CMS conflicting with pop-up box

Tags: jquery

I want to incorporate the pop-up box at the "See full menu" link on this file I uploaded: http://fmsc.org/file/index.html

But when I upload it into our CMS, something clearly conflicts/overrides and it doesn't work: https://fmsc.org/15-mn-gala-pre-gala-content-test

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome Web inspector report the following errors

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fmsc.org/15-mn-gala-pre-gala-content-test' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.fmsc.org/file/classie.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fmsc.org/15-mn-gala-pre-gala-content-test' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.fmsc.org/file/modalEffects.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fmsc.org/15-mn-gala-pre-gala-content-test' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.fmsc.org/file/modernizr.custom.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Meaning you are trying to load **http** resource on a page served on **https**, one way to fix it would be to use **relative path** to the server root using `/file/modernizr.custom.js` instead of `http://www.fmsc.org/file/modernizr.custom.js` ( for example )

Comment: You're brilliant! Thank you so much. And to think I was testing around for a couple hours on that...It works like a charm now.

Comment: Most of the modern browser have a 'Web inspector' or 'Web developer' tools equivalent, they accelerate your troubleshooting by a significant degree